# Laravel Middleware based on a relation

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, administrators can be assigned to jobs, I also have super administrators that can do everything.

Administrators that are not super administrators should only be able to access jobs they are assigned to.

Let's use a rough route for illustration:

`http://localhost:3000/jobs/{job}`

`http://localhost:3000/jobs/{job}/notes{note}`

In this scenario `{job}` is an id acquired via route model binding and a note is attached to a job.

Administrators assigned to jobs are done so via the following relationship method:

```
/**
 * Get the jobs that this admin has access to via the pivot table
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(JobPost::class, 'job_post_admin', 'admin_id', 'job_post_id');
}
```

So I can use `$user->jobs`

I want to be able to say the following - if you're a super admin you can go anywhere, if you're not, you should be restricted to what you've been assigned to.

So if a user only has access to `http://localhost:3000/jobs/{1}` and they go to `http://localhost:3000/jobs/{2}` they should be redirected.

I created a Middleware called Access

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->user()) {

        $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

        if ($user->is_admin) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            if ($user->jobs->contains($job)) {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return response('You do not have sufficient priveledges to perform this action.', 403);
            }
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

However, I'm confused as to how I would get the job ID from the URL.

I have a working MiddleWare that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class Access
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->user()) {

            $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

            $job = $request->vacancy;

            if ($user->is_admin) {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                if ($user->jobs->contains($job)) {
                    return $next($request);
                } else {
                    return response('You do not have sufficient priveledges to perform this action.', 403);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
```

I am now interested though, as without sounding dense I haven't really acknowledged authorization in Laravel, does it have benefits over Middleware?

Comment: Seems like an authorization policy would be a better fit than a middleware.  Did you read the docs on authorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication is different to authorization. Laravel supports both.

You can do what you need using authorisation policies, there is no need for extra middleware.

First create a policy:

```
php artisan make:policy JobsPolicy --model=Job
```

This will make your boilerplate. Then you can add the actions:

```
class JobsPolicy {
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    //If you return true here the policy always succeeds
    public function before(User $user, $ability) { 
        if ($user->is_admin) {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public function view(User $user, Job $job) {
        return $user->jobs->contains($job);
    }

    public function create(User $user) {
        return true; //Return true if the user can create jobs
    }

    public function update(User $user, Job $job) {
          return $user->jobs->contains($job);
    }   
}
```

You need to also register your policy in the `AuthServiceProvider` in the `$policies` array:

```
 protected $policies = [
    Job::class => JobPolicy::class        
];
```

Then you can add the already existing middleware e.g.:

```
Routes::get('jobs/{job}/notes/{note}', ...)->middleware("can:view,job");
```

This will ensure that the currently authenticated user `can`  `view` the `job` specified by the route job parameter.

There's more information in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization)

Comment: So, is it wrong to use Middleware in this sense or is it basically my choice?

Comment: No, all I'm saying Laravel already has the appropriate middleware so you don't need to make your own. You can still use your own middleware but I think the key point to make here is that you need to separate authentication from authorisation because they are different concepts. Restrict your routes to require authenticated admins, but also use the authorisation to restrict those admins to what they can view/edit.

Comment: See, that makes sense. I will give this approach a go as it seems to make more sense.